# How to compare the integer of array with the another variable of type 'int'?

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
vector<int> v;
int N,S,P,Q,data=0,j=0;
cin >> N >> S >> P >> Q;
if((0<N<=10^8)&&(0<S,P,Q<2^31)){
    int arr[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
       arr[i]=arr[i-1]*P+Q; 
    data=arr[0];
    for(int i=1; i<N; i++){
//!request for member 'compare' in 'arr[i]', which is of non-class type 'int'
        if(arr[i].compare(data)==0)
            j++;
        else
            data=arr[i];
    }
    cout<<j;    
}
}
```

When I tried to run the above code, I got the error that is mentioned in the above code. What does the error mean?. Could anyone please explain me in detailed?

Comment: `compare` is for example for `std::string`. Comparing the result with `0` is the same as doing `arr[i] == data`. Didn't you think you could use that?

Comment: It looks like  you already know how to compare 2 `int`s, since you try to check the result against `0`. You just want `if (arr[i] == data)`.

Comment: `arr` is raw array, they don't have any member. Also, `arr[i]` is an int, buitin type, which have neither any member, use @BoBTFish solution

Comment: What do you think this `(0<S,P,Q<2^31)` means? perhaps re-read that part of the book on operators again

Comment: What is integer of array?

Answer (score 2):

To compare two numbers in C++ you can use `==`: `if (arr[i] == data)` is what you want.

Also, the behaviour of `arr[i-1]` on the first iteration of your loop is *undefined*. Do fix that.

`int arr[N];` is a variable length array and is *not* standard C++ but a compiler extension. Use a `std::vector` instead.

Finally `(0<N<=10^8)&&(0<S,P,Q<2^31)`, while syntactically correct is not doing what you think it's doing. Read up on the comma operator. You want to write something like `0 < N && N < 10^8 && 0 < S && 0 < P && Q < 2^31`, assuming that you know that `^` is **not** an exponentation operator in C++

Comment: And do go through the `Finally`.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
 if((0<N<=10^8)&&(0<S,P,Q<2^31))
```

does not even come close to being what you expect.

The comparison operators `<`, `<=`, etc are binary operators, that compare two operands at a time.   You can't chain them like you are to check ranges.   And you cannot check multiple values (`S,P,Q`) either - you need to do all the individual tests, two operands at a time.

Also `^` is a bitwise XOR.   `10^8` is not `10` raised to the power of `8`.   Even better, `^` has lower precedence than comparison operators, so `(0<N<=10^8)` is functionally equivalent to `(((0 < N) <= 10) ^ 8)`.

I suggest strongly you do something you clearly haven't bothered to do - READ a basic elementary text on C++, and understand how expressions work.